# Saving and Loading Tensorflow Model Results in Keras Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For a project that I'm working on, I have created a simple model in TensorFlow that consists of a dense features layer followed by three dense layers.

```py
def build_model(arguments):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(arguments),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    
    return model
```

I am unable to go into more detail about the parameter `arguments`, but the above model function works perfectly fine and can train and save a `.h5` file perfectly fine using the code below.

```py
# Create a path for the saving location of the model
model_dir = log_dir + "\model.h5"

# Save the model
model.save(model_dir)
```

However, when I try to load the model back from the `.h5` file,

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
```

I get the following error message.

```py
  File "sampleModel.py", line 342, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 1
82, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, c
ompile)
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py",
 line 178, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\model_config.py"
, line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py
", line 175, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py"
, line 358, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py",
line 487, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py
", line 175, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py"
, line 358, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\feature_column\base_fea
ture_layer.py", line 141, in from_config
    config['feature_columns'], custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\serialization.
py", line 186, in deserialize_feature_columns
    for c in configs
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\serialization.
py", line 186, in <listcomp>
    for c in configs
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\serialization.
py", line 138, in deserialize_feature_column
    columns_by_name=columns_by_name)
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column
_v2.py", line 2622, in from_config
    config['normalizer_fn'], custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python
\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\serialization.
py", line 273, in _deserialize_keras_object
    obj = module_objects.get(object_name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Looking around, I suspect it has something to do with the `custom_objects` tag for the `load_model` function, but I am not 100% sure of how to implement it.

The only custom objects that I could be using are my loss, which I declare below, and the `accuracy` metric that I use.

`loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`

Comment: You need to include the full traceback, just the error/exception is not really useful.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy My apologies, I added the full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around some more and digging through some Github issues, I believe I've figured out a way around the issue. For my specific situation, I didn't need to save the entire model, rather just the weights. For my configuration I'm using Tensorflow 2.3.0 and Keras 2.4.3.

**SHORT ANSWER:**

Fit your model for at least one epoch, then load in the weights.

**LONG ANSWER:**

To save the weights, I use the following function appended with my model file path above it.

```py
# Create a path for the saving location of the model
model_dir = dir_path + '/model.h5'

# Save the model
model.save_weights(model_dir)
```

I first build my model from my question above and store it in a model object

```py
model = build_model(arguments)
```

I add my loss function and optimizer, then compile my model to make sure it has all relevant features before loading in the weights.

```py
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    
#Declare and set the parametors of the optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, decay=0.001)
    
#Compile the model
model.compile(loss=loss_object, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I found my answer from this line [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26835#ref-issue-428099016), but at the very bottom it says to fit the model for 1 epoch before loading in the weights.

```py
history = model.fit(test_data, batch_size=1, epochs=1)
```

Afterwards, you should be able to load in the weights just fine using the function below.

```py
model.load_weights(model_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "arguments" is a list of feature_columns which you have created.
Assuming you have not created any custom training objects.
Use the TF format for saving the model.
This is tested for TF 2.3

```
model.save("./my_model/",save_format="tf")
```

For Loading model:

```
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/my_model')
```

Comment: I've tried your above code and I still am getting the same errors. The only custom objects that I can think of that I might be using are `loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` and when I compile the model, I use `accuracy` as my metric.

Comment: Can you share a standalone code to reproduce this error? Along with this also share the python and TensorFlow versions you are using. Because both the objects you mentioned are provided by TensorFlow and are serializable.